# Can I take a manual snapshot of AWS Elasticsearch and store it different region s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-s3, devops

I am a newbie to AWS and Elastic Search. I am trying to take manual snapshot of my Elastic Search indices and store it in S3 bucket which is in a different region as that of AWS ElasticSearch.

While registering it throws me following error.

```
{
   "error":{
      "root_cause":[
         {
            "type":"blob_store_exception",
            "reason":"Failed to check if blob [master.dat] exists"
         }
      ],
      "type":"blob_store_exception",
      "reason":"Failed to check if blob [master.dat] exists",
      "caused_by":{
         "type":"amazon_s3_exception",
         "reason":"The bucket is in this region: ap-south-1. Please use this region to retry the request (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 301; Error Code: 301 Moved Permanently; Request ID: 1.....A; S3 Extended Request ID: 4....=)"
      }
   },
   "status":500
}
```

I see no where in documentation that it is not supported.
Below is my Access Policy for this user.

````
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:PassRole",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::myAccountId:role/myRole",
                "arn:aws:s3:::snapBucket"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::snapBucket/*",
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "es:ESHttpPost",
                "es:ESHttpPut"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:es:us-west-1:myAccountId:domain/myDomainId"
            ]
        }
    ]
}


and below is my python client to register the repo. 


import boto3
import requests
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth

host = 'myHost'
region = 'us-west-1' # For example, us-west-1
service = 'es'

credentials = boto3.Session().get_credentials()
awsauth = AWS4Auth(credentials.access_key, credentials.secret_key, region, service, session_token=credentials.token)

# Register repository
path = '_snapshot/my-snapshot-repo' # the Elasticsearch API endpoint
url = host + path

payload = {
  "type": "s3",
  "settings": {
    "bucket": "snapBucket",
    "base_path": "elasticsearchindices/testSnaps",
    "endpoint" : "ap-south-1",
    "role_arn": "arn:aws:iam::myAccountId:role/myRole"
  }
}

headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}

r = requests.put(url, auth=awsauth, json=payload, headers=headers)

print(r.status_code)
print(r.text)```

Is this allowed ? Am i doing something wrong ? 
Thanks in Adv :)
````

Comment: Are you using the same region to "register?" AWS S3 api is quite particular on specifying region

Comment: No its not the same region . My ES and S3 are in two different regions. But I am specifying the same while registering.